# Resolve all not using names

Tags: .net, unity-container

I got an interface called `IStartable` which is implemented by several concretes. All are registered to `UnityContainer` using `RegisterType` without a name.

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
_container.ResolveAll<IStartable>().ForEach(startable => startable.Start());
//application lifetime
_container.ResolveAll<IStartable>().ForEach(startable => startable.Stop());
```

How can I achieve that without having to name all registrations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, you cannot. You need to name all registrations.

Indeed, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648211.aspx):

> 5: If you want to create more than one registration using the same registered
>   type, you can create a named
>   (non-default) registration by
>   specifying a name as a parameter [...]